# Add point to line graph in ggplot when x axis is in Date format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I built a line graph using ggplot that shows changes in two different types of monetary contributions over years for a company. I am trying to add a red dot on the graph during certain years to denote specific events. Since my x axis is in Date format, I am struggling to use geom_point to add in the dot.

My data looks something like this:

```
money1       money2       year
6000         8000         2011-01-01
7000         1400         2012-01-01
4500         3000         2013-01-01
9000         5000         2014-01-01
```

The code I used to create the date format is `data$year<-lubridate::ymd(data$year, truncated = 2L)` because the dates originally appeared just as years (ex. 2011, 2012, 2013, etc.).

To create my graph, I used:

```
data %>% 
  filter(company=="minsur") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year))+
  geom_line(aes(y=money1, color="Money1"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=money2, color="Money2"))
```

I want to add a red dot to the graph during the year 2012 (where it falls on the y axis is unimportant for now).

I've tried:

```
data %>% 
  filter(company=="minsur") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year))+
  geom_line(aes(y=money1, color="Money1"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=money2, color="Money2")) 
  geom_point(aes(x="2012-01-01", y=3000),size = 1,colour = "Red")
```

But I get this error: *Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale*

I've tried many other techniques and have yet to get it to run without an error of some kind. Does anyone know how to format the geom_point to work with my Date x axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have "2012-01-1", R considers this character data. You need to make it a date.

```
geom_point(aes(x = as.Date("2012-01-01"), y=3000), size = 1, colour = "Red")
```